# ¿Como usar background-image con props? - React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Estoy practicando con REACT JS y no estoy encontrando información al respecto de como hacer de un background-image, un componente, ya que esta es una propiedad unicamente de css y creo que no puedo meter props en el css.

La sección principal de la página consta de varios cuadros o bloques puestos en display:grid, cada cuadro tiene principalmente un texto y una imagen de fondo distinto del otro, lo que busco es algo como esto

[image: Ejemplo de lo que busco]

Un cuadro con su imagen y su texto o título superpuesto, van a ser muchos de estos cuadros por lo que necesito hacerlo un componente para simplificar el código...suponiendo que este sea el componente de la foto de arriba **como tendría que codear este componente?**

```
function box(props) { return <div className="main-container">  </div>;}
```

Inicialmente lo que había hecho fué simplemente poner la imagen en el componente con la etiqueta `<img src="..."/>` y abajo un h3 para el texto o título de ese cuadro, ambos atributos con props, me quedó muy lindo, pero de este modo no puedo superponer el texto sobre la imagen, me lo pone arriba o abajo o al costado y me mueve toda la grilla de cuadros... creo que la unica forma es usando la etiqueta "background"

Comment: probaste usando background-image en css? y usando background-size para ajustarla al contenedor? Muy lindo el gatito.

Comment: Te puedes basar en este [ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/rimuru/rpho7ytf). Simplemente necesitas usar las propiedades `position: relative` y `position: absolute` de forma correcta, y las propiedades top, bottom, right y left para alinear los elementos correctamente

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar la propiedad style para aplicar estilos en línea al componente. Aquí te muestro un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```
function Box(props) {
  const { imageUrl, title } = props;
  const containerStyle = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    position: 'relative',
    width: '200px',
    height: '200px',
  };

  const textStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: '0',
    left: '0',
    padding: '10px',
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
  };

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <h3 style={textStyle}>{title}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Revisar [answer]